# What is the Bedrock Hypixel IP for Xbox?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

What's the server IP is for Hypixel Xbox 360? I have already tried the normal mc.hypixel.net IP address.

Comment: Have you got any error messages? Because two things might be blocking you: 1- 360 Minecraft will only accept bog-standard or realm servers, and nothing else or 2- the Xbox 360 version of minecraft is out of date with the current version, and they can't play together. Hell, I used to play Minecraft on 360 and I cant remember it supporting cross play. You could join friends via the Xbox functions to do so, but you could not join someone outside the xbox world. I can't even remember a place where you could put in an IP to join something directly.

Comment: At the end of the day, if I'm wrong and actually can connect directly to an IP... do you get an error message? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at versions of Minecraft, we can see the Xbox 360 version is classified as [Legacy](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Version_history#Legacy_Console_Edition); It has been abandoned since 2019.

So that means no updates. And I would guess that your server runs Minecraft on the current version, which would make it refuse the connection to anybody trying to connect with another version.

And more: I can't seem to find an Xbox 360 version of Minecraft Bedrock, that is the current, universal version.

So at the end of the day, I would guess that you cannot play on external servers in any way on Xbox 360.

Answer (score 0):

Hypixel is only for the Java edition of *Minecraft* so it's impossible to play on an Xbox 360 which is on the Bedrock edition.